# Using jQuery .serialize() within ajax array to pass the PHP $_POST as Variables?

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

This is the jQuery code i'm using to send the form details to a php function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    jQuery('.submit').click(function(){
        var str = $("#ajaxForms").serialize();
        var data = {
            action: 'myajax-submit',
            serialize: str,
            beforeSend: function(){
                alert('Sending...');
            }
        };  
        jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data,  function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
        return false;   
    });
});
```

and this is the php function:

```
function myajax_submit() {
    $whatever = $_POST['serialize'];
    echo $whatever;
    die(); 
}
```

Everything works, but when the alert box appears the text displays a string of values from my html form `#ajaxForms`. I believe this is because the php function echos the `$_POST['serialize']`.

In my form i have an input box such as:

`<input id="postID" name="postID" value="First Name" type="text"  />`

but when i try echo the `$_POST['postID']` variable in the php it doesn't display anything in the alert box.

I thought by sending the form data serialized to the php function i could use the $_POST variable associated with the form inputs?

Help appreciated. :)

Comment: I don't know PHP but wouldn't your postID be a member of the serialize object you passed as data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By serializing the form inputs with jQuery's serialize you create a string like:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5&postID=10
```

In order to get the postId you need to de-serialize the $_POST['serialize']. In order to do so you should do something like:

```
parse_str($_POST['serialize'], $whatever);
```

Now on `$whatever['postID']` is what you are searching for.

Edit: Fixing parse_str() :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the following but there is no result: `function myajax_submit() {
 $whatever = parse_str($_POST['serialize']);
 echo $whatever['postID'];
 die(); 
}`

Comment: @MattStrange Do an `echo $_POST['serialize'];` What are you getting?

Comment: Just the echo in the function i get a string from the form, postID=First+Name&GreetingAll=Hello+Everyone!

Comment: @MattStrange Ah, sorry my bad. I wrote parse_str incorrectly. Please see the edit

Comment: Thanks mobius, your the man! seems to be all in working order :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  Spent hours looking for how to do this, since I had no idea what to look up!

Answer (score 7):

You're implementing [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in a wrong way. `.serialize()` returns a string. So, when you pass `serialize: str` to `$.post()`, the form itself is not added any more, but a plain string containing the serialized form.

The code below is correct, using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (see the commented lines).

```
jQuery('.submit').click(function(){
    var str = $("#ajaxForms").serialize();
    // If you realllly. want a parameter serialize, uncomment the following line
    // str += '&serialize=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
    str += '&action=myajax-submit';
    jQuery.ajax(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: str,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert('Sending...');
        }
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Hey Rob, I tried the following code but receive an empty result for that i don't know why, i removed the  `method: 'POST'` to as wordpress handles the jQuery differently. I'm following this guide, http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Use my code, literally. You can use `jQuery.post`, if you want, but **`beforeSend`** will not work. See this code: http://pastebin.com/4DVQih3i