# jquery serialize or submiting the form not working with selected options in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, serialization

I have a problem, and couldn't find any solutions. Maybe someone had similar problem. Here is form:

```
<form class="filter-form" name="filter_form" action="[url]" method="POST">

<select name="active_filter" style="display: none;">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>


<select name="date_filter" style="display: none;">
    <option value="date_desc">Desc</option>
    <option value="date_asc">Asc</option>
</select>


</form>
```

I'm setting selected="selected" on options with jQuery (i have to do that because I have styled "drop downs"). After jQuery form looks like this:

```
<form class="filter-form" name="filter_form" action="[url]" method="POST">

<select name="active_filter" style="display: none;">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="active" selected="selected">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>

<select name="date_filter" style="display: none;">
    <option value="date_desc">Desc</option>
    <option value="date_asc" selected="selected">Asc</option>
</select>

</form>
```

But then I run

```
$(".filter-form").serialize();
```

or just submiting the form

```
$(".filter-form").submit();
```

I get response only with first option elements:

```
"active_filter=all&date_filter=date_desc"
```

This problem occurs only with Firefox. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

P.S. sorry for my broken English ^^,

Comment: I expect "active_filter=active&date_filter=date_asc"

Answer (score 0):

style="display: none;"

This is a problem

Set them to visibility:hidden and position:absolute instead. The fields will not be sent to the server with display:none, but will be with visibility:hidden. By also toggling "position" to "absolute" you should get the same visual effect.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that didn't helped :/ still nothing

Comment: Look this answer may be it will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917622/using-jquery-serialize-within-ajax-array-to-pass-the-php-post-as-variables)

Comment: zeshan - no, there is not my problem :( here I don't get selected options, not the problem sending them to the server

Comment: Can you Please try this 
name="active_filter[]"

Let me know what result comes after adding this.

Comment: Also have a look here 
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/66735/default-selected-option-in-firefox-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Firefox, it's working fine.

```
$(function(){
    $("#disp").text($(".filter-form").serialize());
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/m8uXd/