# How to use a $_POST Variable in another file and function

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli

First set of code, on separate page than second

```
<?php
include 'HytecFunctions.php';

if((isset($_POST["name"]))  ) {
$name = $_POST["name"];
addName($name);
}
```

Second and Separate Page code

```
function updateScore() {

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = connectDB();

// Score Update
$name = "Test1";
// $name = getName();
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Score FROM Names WHERE Name=?");
$sql->bind_param('s',$name);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($score);
$sql->fetch();
$sql->close();
```

The user enters a name and it is entered into a database as seen in the first code snippet. Then I need to use that $name in a separate code file so that it looks more like this, and stays dynamic with the user's name.

```
function updateScore() {

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = connectDB();

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Score FROM Names WHERE Name=?");
$sql->bind_param('s',$name);
```

I need the name to be entered and then used here to bind the user's name to the prepare statement.

```
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($score);
$sql->fetch();
$sql->close();
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Pass the `$_POST[]` variable through jquery. Look at this [Using jQuery .serialize() within ajax array to pass the PHP $_POST as Variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917622/using-jquery-serialize-within-ajax-array-to-pass-the-php-post-as-variables)

Comment: You can keep the $_POST['name'] in session variable and after completion of your task you can unset the value.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback both of you, using $_SESSION works like a charm!